# Command executed via ssh

Tags: ssh, centos, centos-6, command-history

On CentOS 6, how can I tell what commands were executed via someone that ssh'ed into as root?   I looked in /root/.bash_history.  I also ssh'ed into myself and did a history but the only commands I don't recognize are:

```
  799  kill jetiyeklrb
  800  kill 3310
  801  top
  802  ifconfig -a
  803  ifconfig -a | grep 58:91
  804  ls -l exe
  805  cd /usr/bin
  806  ls
  807  history
  808   ls -l exe
  809  exit
```

For background, I left remote SSH into my CentOS 6 laptop open. A hacker had brute forced my laptop's root password and installed Unix.Trojan.DDoS_XOR-1 FOUND (This is classification I got from ClamAV).  I'm trying to figure out what the hacker did while on my computer (if possible).

**Edit**: My question was a little unclear.  I'm asking how do I get what the hacker did while on my computer.  After further research, it seems most hackers hide their tracks so it may not be possible.  The reason I put the above commands was to show where I've looked and what I noticed.  I understand what each of these commands do and none of these commands install the DDoS_XOR-1 virus.  Last night I noticed in the directory /var/log there was a 2 year period where the secure logs were missing.

Comment: I'm sorry this happened to you.  In future I recommend using keys, and disabling ssh to root, and disabling ssh passwords completely. You can still su to root after logging in with a key as a user of group wheel or sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just describe all commands one by one:

```
kill jetiyeklrb
```

An attempt at killing (terminating) a process called `jetiyeklrb`, but this is not valid syntax for the `kill` command. (This may not be a very skilled intruder.)

```
kill 3310
```

Killing presumably the process mentioned above by its PID.

```
top
```

Checking running processes, maybe to make sure the killed process wasn't stuck?

```
ifconfig -a
```

Printing network interface information (like MAC address, IP address and some transmission statistics) for all interfaces

```
ifconfig -a | grep 58:91
```

Printing only the line from the previous output that contains `58:91`, so likely a MAC address (network interface hardware address, used for many things including Wake-on-LAN)

```
ls -l exe
```

Printing a detailed listing of the file (or directory) called `exe`. (Perhaps checking whether it has permissions set to allow execution?)

```
cd /usr/bin
```

Changing directory to `/usr/bin`, where all non-essential executable binaries are stored.

```
ls
```

Listing names of all files in the current directory (`/usr/bin`).

```
history
```

Printing the 1000 (configurable value) most recent commands executed.

```
ls -l exe
```

Printing a detailed listing of the `exe` file (or directory, but given the name and current directory, probably an executable file containing that trojan you mentioned) again, presumably to check permission to execute. The space in front excludes it from command history on some systems, but apparently not this one.

```
exit
```

Logging out of SSH.

Comment: I was asking for a way to tell what commands the hacker executed.  I understand what the commands I listed above do.  The hacker did more than just execute the above commands to install XOR-1 virus.  I'm trying to figure out what else the hacker did.

Comment: Like your edit points out, this may be impossible without other mechanisms to track changes - I would start over with a clean install to ensure no traces are left, and follow @Guy Gastineau's suggestions above.